# Will my account be closed if i stop participating on Physics SE?

Tags: support, user-accounts, suspensions

I just noticed that the account of a formerly-active user whom I hadn't seen active since he was suspended a while back has been suspended again for a period of one year. He is not even participating on this site anymore so I don't understand the reason for this suspension. Will my account too be closed if I stop participating?

Comment: @Shog9 this is not what i asked. You may delete this question.

Comment: I hope my edit summary shows Shog9 how silly that sort of a wording is?

Comment: @DImension10 this is still not what i asked. It will be useless if i edit it again to what i originally asked, because i am sure someone like Shog will come again and change it; and anyway they are not going to give any answers. Should i delete it myself ?

Comment: @user10001 Its been bought up many times already, a lot of people are unhappy and very much in the dark. Leave it, your account ofcourse wont be suspended.

Comment: @annav We _never_ suspend for off site activities. And we don't really care about the size of his reputation, we won't suspend to reduce that either.

Comment: @Manishearth Why previous comments were deleted ? In particular the first one "why downvotes ?" which didn't even have any mention of Ron's name in it ?

Comment: @user10001 I didn't delete them, I don't know. But comments are designed to be ephermal, so if they're going off topic or aren't relevant anymore (eg the comments asking for the question to be edited) they get deleted. Comments aren't supposed to hold anything permanent. They can be deleted without reason.

Comment: @Manishearth Then i can only request to please not delete Mostafa's comment. Its not off topic.

Comment: @user10001 I'm not deleting it now, but I can't make that promise, especially not on behalf of the team. Firstly, comments can be deleted at will, and secondly, it _is_ off topic to the discussion, only serving to re ignite a discussion that happened a long time ago.

Comment: @Manishearth Its actually the title of the question which is irrelevant to the discussion (specially after shree Shog9 jee came and changed it). We all  know what the real question is and Mustafa's comment is completely relevant to that. Anyway, I won't reply to any comments anymore.

Comment: @user10001: I'm sorry, I thought it was pretty close - you seemed concerned at the thought that you might be suspended for inactivity; if that's not where your concern lies, please clarify.

Comment: @Shog9 Was it you who deleted previous comments ?

Comment: Yeah - they were pretty derailed. @dimen

Comment: @Shog9: Did you mean to ping user10001?

Comment: And @Mostafa's comment is gone.

Comment: It wasn't user10001 derailing the comments. So, no.

Comment: @Shog9: No, I was asking whether you were replying to user 10001, who asked "Was it you who deleted previous comments?"...

Comment: @user10001, you are correct that my comment was also off-topic. Now that Mostafa's comment is gone, I have deleted my comment.

Comment: @Manishearth as my comment was deleted by the powers that be, I suppose because I was answering the original question that I could see clicking on the edit version, better delete your answer to my non-comment now. I have to say that this nit picking censoring, by whoever, is not conducive to a good intellectual environment.

Answer (score 7):

> He is not even participating on this site anymore so i don't understand the reason for this suspension.

He was participating, slightly. I can't provide details on the exact reasons for suspension<sup>1</sup>, but I can tell you that he was suspended for his participation (more accurately, something he did in the course of that participation), not for his lack of it.

> Will my account too be closed if i stop participating ?

No. People are free to come and go from the site if they don't break any other rules. We don't suspend accounts for inactivity.

<sup>1. Moderators are bound by common decency to not discuss the details behind a suspension of a person who by definition isn't here to defend themselves.</sup>

Comment: "He was participating, slightly". Who ? How do you know who is being referred to in the question :)

Comment: @user10001 it's visible to anyone, in the revisions history of the question.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: user10001's comment is supposed to indicate that it's impossible to talk about this without       mentioning the user. Did you see the '": )"'?--------

Answer (score 0):

There are **no** measures in place to suspend registered accounts (with rep>1) that do pause their participation.

So if you **wish** to be suspended, then flag one of your own questions for a diamond moderator, and ask them (ideally you'd ask politely) to suspend you. There's no need to create extra work for the mods by forcing a suspension through repeatedly breaking the rules.

I saw some of the material that led to the suspension in question. Those comments have been deleted now, as they broke the site rules. That was the reason for the suspension: not inactivity, but rather rule-breaking activity.

The poster has explicitly insisted that he would go on breaking the rules until he was suspended. He's done that on more than one StackExchange site, and that's been his "personal policy" for over a year now, so this wasn't a one-off event in time or in location.

He's now suspended.

To prosper, the site needs enforcement of the rules. This poster wanted to be suspended.

And now, the rules are enforced, and the poster is suspended. So we've all got what we need. If anyone has a problem with the suspension, then they should address their complaints to the poster himself, who actively sought out and engineered the necessity for the suspension.

Comment: I don't get it. Ron Maimon requested suspension ? !

Comment: Like you I too can say a lot of words. Where is the proof? Anyway even in this question I have seen moderators deleting comments which broke no rules.

Comment: It's best not to discuss the Ron suspension here. Also, you seem to be talking about the previous suspension, not this one.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS Yes. Here and on skeptics.se. I suggest you or anyone else might consider asking him, off-site, if you want confirmation or more information. But please do bear in mind that many users do not want to be contacted off-site. Users will generally edit their profiles to include off-site contact information, if they do wish to be contacted off-site.

Comment: @user10001 comments are designed to be ephemeral and disposable. Comment-deletion can happen for a very large number of reasons. "Why downvotes?" is a paragon of an unconstructive comment that should be (and often is) deleted on sight.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I asked this to Manishearth. Also every user has right to ask why his question is being downvoted. No?

Comment: @user10001 No. It's just noise and clutter. It's really much better to not do it. If people want to provide a comment suggesting ways to improve the question, they're free to, when they downvote. Asking for reasons can look like whining. Don't worry - most of us do it initially, until we learn that it's bad etiquette. And voting is anonymous, so assuming that you know who downvoted you is presumptious, and unlikely to engender goodwill.

Comment: @user10001 [here is one example of Ron daring the mods to suspend him](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1952/politically-motivated-deletion-of-answer/1953#comment5784_1953), and [here is an example where he states that he ignores all policies and site rules](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1952/politically-motivated-deletion-of-answer/1953#comment5779_1953).

Comment: @Mad Scientist This resulted into his one month suspension last year. After that he was participating only slightly to answer to comments to his questions. So why he has been [suspended for one year again](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/4864/ron-maimon)? Where are the proofs for his bad behavior which resulted into this suspension ?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers this is your personal view which is not justified and is not shared by most of the community members. There should be at least some rules that moderators should follow in deleting comments and [suspending users accounts](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/4864/ron-maimon).

Comment: @user10001  if you have **evidence** of what "most of the community members" think about comments, then please post it. And there are indeed rules that moderators follow when suspending user accounts.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: Haven't you seen the evidence being cleared?   See [this](http://motls.blogspot.in/2013/08/discussion-on-old-and-new-theoretical.html#comment-1045938696) list.

Comment: @user10001 I have not seen the incident that caused the newest suspension, and it is likely deleted now. But if you observed Rons behaviour on multiple other sites, it is reasonably to extrapolate that some similar behaviour likely got him suspended. All Physics mods know the reason, and SE reviewed the suspension. I see no reason at all to doubt them that there was a suspension-worthy offense in light of Ron's previous behaviour on multiple sites.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS, that discussion isn't taking place here. It's not evidence of how the members of *this* community think. At best, you could point out that the people there are using names that are similar to user names here. But it's still just a few people having that discussion. There are more than (23*36 = ) 828 users with at least 300 rep total and (9*36 = ) 324 users with at least 100 rep earned since July 1. *That* is people mean when they refer to the community.

Comment: @ColinMcFaul: If only you bothered looking at that. It's a list of deleted questions.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS, you're missing my point. My point is that there are only a few users of this site participating in that discussion, and the only way to check how this community feels about those deleted questions is to ask *here*.

Comment: @ColinMcFaul: You're not getting my point. My point is that it is hard to give evidence, because      those (highly upvoted (!))     questions are deleted.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS, we're off-topic again. This question is about deleting *comments*, not *answers*. If you want to provide evidence of the community's views on those questions, there is an easy way to do that: *ask about them right here, in Meta*.

Comment: @ColinMcFaul: And *again*, you don't get my point. You said (in a now - deleted comment) that you were asking evidence for the community doesn't want blablabla. I said, that the evidence is censored, so I unfortunately can't give it.